# How to find the API name of field from a label of field of a particular sobject?

Tags: salesforce

How to find the API name of field from an label of field from a particular sobject.

This was pretty bad to find the field api name in salesforce, It is an indeed a trivial question which many of developer folks find out tough while working on projects.

Putting here as an code snippet for searching easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code snippet to find out the api name of the field based on the label of an object.

```
public static String getMyAPIName(String objectName, String fieldLabel ) {
    
    SObjectType type = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName);
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = type.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    
    for(String strField : mfields.keySet())
    {
        SObjectField fl = mfields.get(strField);
        if(fieldLabel == fl.getDescribe().getlabel())
        {
            return strField;
        }
    }
    
    return '';
}
```

Comment: +1 from me, it's cool because it doesn't waste SOQL queries. But it has some limitations. 1. You can spend time calling `getDescribe()` at ~40 standard and up to 800 custom fields on Account (and pray you don't have Person Accounts enabled). 2. It stops after it found 1st match, label doesn't have to be unique. 3. If you use Translation Workbench - these field labels might be dutifully shown in French, German etc and your logic can start to fail, work only for users that have same language as org's master language...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName, QualifiedApiName, Label
FROM FieldDefinition 
WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Account' AND Label = 'Parent Account'
```

outputs "ParentId" just fine, no describes and loops

Comment: This approach is good to easily find the field in single statement, but here we have to make the SOQL query for sure, but in the my answer We don't have to go for soql. I checked executing the both code snippets and found that, all the stats are same only difference is that in this approach we need to make atleast one SOQL call.

Comment: 1 query can be acceptable price, especially if you'd use stuff like platform cache to store the result. "Describes" used to be expensive operation (they still are but SF decided to not count them towards the CPU time limit). It's simpler to run a query or REST API callout than hunt for such code snippet. Old SF orgs can easily reach the limit of 800 custom fields on key objects and then the loop becomes non-trivial. Even funnier if you have field label but no object name - good luck running describe on all objects, all fields... Different tools for different needs